# IndexedDB records as asynchronous iterator

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, iterator, record, indexeddb

While attempting to retrieve records from an IndexedDB store as an async iterator, not finding any existing recipe, I came up with this code which seems to work.

```
function itemPromise(req) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        req.onsuccess = (event) => {
            let cursor = event.target.result;
            resolve([cursor, itemPromise(req)]);
        };
        req.onerror = (event) => {
            reject(event.target)
        };
    });
}

function iterRecords(req) {

    let promise = itemPromise(req);

    return {
        async next() {
            let [cursor, nextPromise] = await promise;
            promise = nextPromise;
            if (cursor) {
                cursor.continue();
                return Promise.resolve({done: false, value: cursor.value});
            } else {
                return Promise.resolve({done: true, value: null});
            }
        }
    }
}


async function main() {
    let db = await getDb('myDatabase'); // gets a promise on datbase
    let trans = db.transaction(['myStore'], 'readonly');
    let store = trans.objectStore('myStore');
    let req = store.openCursor();
    let iter = iterRecords(req);

    while(true) {
        let {done, value} = await iter.next();
        if (done) {
            break;
        }
        console.log(value);
    }
}
```

As it is a bit complicated/convoluted I wonder if I am not missing something in my approach. I'd love some feedback before reinventing the wheel... or inventing a very bad wheel.

Note: my code is not using `async *function` or `for await ... of` as they are not supported yet by all browser.

Comment: https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb is a popular library with similar support for async iterators, but it's implemented with an async generator so it's not the same as what you did.

Comment: Hate to be that guy but I think that the [code review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to post this :)